# YII2 Active record - Не работает условие даты при использовании joinWith

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2, activerecord

Есть две таблицы Employee и Schedule, schedule связано с employee через schedule.employee = employee.id

Нужно отобрать все расписания сотрудников за конкретный день.

В SQL запрос выглядит так:

```
select * from employee 
left join schedule on schedule.employee  = employee.id
where schedule.date = <ДАТА>
```

В Yii модели у меня созданы через gii, соответственно и связи.
В контроллере у меня следующее

```
$qEmployee = Employee::find()->joinWith('schedules')->where(['schedule.date'=>$curDate]);
$Employee = $qEmployee->all();
```

Дату задаю в формате YYYY-mm-dd, тип в БД - date

Проблема в том, что если указать дату, которая есть в базе - в $Employee->schdeules попадут все записи за все даты. Если указать дату, которой нет в базе - будет нулевой результат.

При этом указание условий по другим полям этой таблицы работает корректно.

Также если делать выборку напрямую из таблицы Schedule, с указанием даты, не делая join, то результат будет правильный.

В чем может быть дело? второй день не могу решить!

Comment: В логе mysql выполняются такие запросы, зачем выполняется второй запрос просто для employee=1 не могу понять
11 Query SET NAMES 'utf8'
     11 Query SELECT `employee`.* FROM `employee` LEFT JOIN `schedule` ON `employee`.`id` = `schedule`.`employee` WHERE (`schedule`.`date`='2015-05-30') AND (`schedule.employee`=1)
     11 Query SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `employee`
     11 Query SHOW CREATE TABLE `employee`
     11 Query SELECT * FROM `schedule` WHERE `employee`=1
     11 Query SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `schedule`
     11 Query SHOW CREATE TABLE `schedule`
     11 Quit

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте как-то так:

```
$qEmployee = Employee::find()->joinWith([
    'schedules' => function($query) use ($curDate) {
        $query->andWhere(['date'=>$curDate])
    } 
]);
```

Суть в том, что нужно правильно построить запрос. Для этого надо в связанную таблицу передать условие, по которому и будет идти выборка, что мы и делаем с помощью анонимной функции.